# Redmine unable to start 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, redmine

I' unable to start my redmine after a gem installation. I did a clean installation from the github and I followed this [installation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall)  but I still have the same error. There's no output in the redmine (production.log). This is the apache log :

```
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:48.7305 3216/6db5c1bea700 Pool2/Spawner.h:738 ]: [App 3326 stdout] 
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.4676 3216/6db5c1bea700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:301 ]: Preloader for /inlibro/opt/redmine started on PID 3326, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.25100/generation-124/backends/preloader.3326
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5183 3346/0x000000083b50a8(Worker 1) utils.rb:71 ]: *** Exception NoMethodError in Rack application object (undefined method `clean_path_info' for Rack::Utils:Module) (process 3346, thread 0x000000083b50a8(Worker 1)):
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:28:in `block in match?'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:27:in `map'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:27:in `match?'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:110:in `call'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5184 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5185 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5185 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5185 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
[ 2016-06-28 08:26:53.5185 3216/6db5c0040700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1182 ]: [App 3326 stderr]     from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
[Tue Jun 28 08:26:53 2016] [error] [client 199.38.101.93] Premature end of script headers:
```

This my environment:

- RubyGems Environment:

  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:

    - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
    - /home/mehdi/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
  - :update_sources => true

    - :verbose => true
    - :benchmark => false
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:

    - http://rubygems.org/
  - OS :

    - Debian 7.11
  - Redmine:

    - Redmine 3.1-stable (branch)

Let me know if anything else is needed!

Comment: Paste the entire apache output for the `ExceptionError`. Which module are you using to load the application in Apache?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I'm using: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10

Comment: @hjpotter92 I added a few lines for the first run, but that's it, that's all I have.